# I'm using h2 DB in my Spring Boot project. I'm able to connect to h2 consle, but database is not getting created

Tags: java, spring-boot

This is my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.2</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.shubham</groupId>
<artifactId>Order_service</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Order_service</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <version>1.4.193</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I'm using h2 DB in my spring boot project. I'm able to connect to h2 console, but database is not getting created. This is my entity class. I have mentioned the table name here but it is not creating a table in the h2 console. Based on the above code, am I missing something? I don't know what's the problem.

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
@Entity
@Table(name ="ORDER_TB" )
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Order {

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getQty() {
    return qty;
}

public void setQty(int qty) {
    this.qty = qty;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}

@Id
private int id;
private String name;
private int qty;
private double price;

}
```

Comment: have you tried setting `spring.jpa.generate-ddl: true` in your application config?

Answer (score 0):

One remark: you labeled the issue for `spring-batch` but your pom file contains an `spring-boot-starter-web`. this a little bit confused.

But, I reproduced your code on my machine in a clean new empty project and it was working for me when I configured the h2 database with the following settings:

```
# H2
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
```

When I comment out the `spring.datasource.url` with `#` like this:

```
# H2
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
# spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
```

It did not generated the table.

Can you check the `spring.datasource.url` exists and correct in your `application.properties`?

When we connect to H2 database via browser we should use the same JDBC URL otherwise it will be connected to an Empty database. (The other possible mistake is a typo here)

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but it's not working for me. And by mistakenly I chose spring-batch tag. Can you give any other solution?

Comment: @ShubhamNavghare `mistakenly I chose spring-batch tag`: I updated the tags as needed.

Answer (score 0):

In your configuration file, if you already set your port and the other settings, also add this code if you don't already have.

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl: true
```